# Subtracting numbers from inputted array

Tags: python, subtraction

I'm very new to Python and trying to figure out how to subtract numbers that are in arrays that were user inputted. For example, earlier in my program I have:
`

```
peakone = raw_input("Where is the next large peak?: ")
next_peak.append(peakone)
peaktwo = raw_input("Where is the next large peak?: ")
next_peak.append(peaktwo)
```

Now I want to subtract peakone from peaktwo and save this value as a third. What is the best way to do this, if there is one?

Comment: Are the numbers integers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
peakthree = float(peaktwo) - float(peakone)
```

What you get from `raw_input` is a string, so you need to convert it to a numeric type, like `float` or `int`. Consider writing your code like this:

```
def get_next_peak():
    return float(raw_input("Where is the next large peak?: "))

next_peak = []
next_peak.append(get_next_peak())
next_peak.append(get_next_peak())
next_peak.append(next_peak[1] - next_peak[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `next_peak` as a `list`

Cast the input to`int` or `float`

```
next_peak = []
peakone = raw_input("Where is the next large peak?: ")
next_peak.append(int(peakone))
peaktwo = raw_input("Where is the next large peak?: ")
next_peak.append(int(peaktwo))
print next_peak[0] - next_peak[1]
```

Can change `int` to `float` if needed